# Export variable for a target in POSIX Make

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, posix

In GNU Make you can export a variable for a target:

```
foo: export X=42
foo:
    echo $$X
    # Call several more commands that use $X.
```

Is there a way to do this in portable POSIX Make? So far, I've found two ways. The first is to basically merge all commands into one:

```
foo:
    export X=42; \
        echo $$X; \
        # Call several more commands that use $X.
```

This is bad because now everything is bundled together. The second is to call `$(MAKE)`:

```
foo:
    $(MAKE) foo_ X=42
foo_:
    echo $$X
    # Call several more commands that use $X.
```

But this has an extra call to make again. Is there a better way?

Comment: Using make variables, instead? For instance you can replace your `echo $$X` by `echo $(X)`. Note: I am very surprised that your second solution (with recursive make) works.

Comment: The commands I am calling are reading the value of `X` from the environment, so that won't work, unless I do something like `export X=$(X); cmd1`.

Comment: I see. The simplest solution is probably to set the variable on the command line by invoking make with `make X=42`. This way 1. the make `X` variable is defined and set to 42, even if it is set to another value in the Makefile 2. the shell environment variable `X` is defined and set to 42 for all recipes. If you cannot use this (for instance because it is make that computes the value) the recursive make solution is probably the simplest. Note: forget the last part of my previous comment, I didn't read your question with enough attention.

Comment: Mind reposting your comment as an answer? If there isn't a better answer, I will accept it after a couple of days.

Comment: Done. I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114730/is-it-possible-to-set-environment-variables-in-makefile-to-be-used-after/52115997#52115997) at least one other question about these make - shell variable interactions.  And also [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813516/export-environment-variables-from-makefile-to-userland-environment/51816459#51816459). Maybe will you find something useful there? And I remember that [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist) also answered similar questions, if you can find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to set the variable on the command line by invoking make with:

```
make X=42
```

This way:

1. The make `X` variable is defined and set to 42, even if it is set to another value in the Makefile.
2. The shell environment variable `X` is defined and set to 42 for all recipes.

If you cannot use this (for instance because it is make that computes the value) the recursive make solution is probably the best option:

```
ifeq ($(X),)
X := <some-make-magic>

all:
    $(MAKE) X=$(X) all
else
all:
    <recipe-that-uses-X-environment-variable>
endif
```

Comment: One nit: POSIX Make doesn't have `ifeq`, so the condition should probably be inside a rule and in sh syntax; something like `if [ "$(X)" = "" ]; then ...; else ...; fi`

Comment: Ooops, you're right, this is not POSIX make. Sorry.